# Does my description of wok wall make any sense to native speakers?

Tags: sentence-usage

I am going to describe a wall called wok wall in China. Can I say "a Wok wall is one with a semi-circle extension on the top middle, making the top of wall like a wok with a pair of handles and its cover in place". Can you please tell whether this description makes any sense to native speakers. Thank you[image]

Comment: Those are similar to Dutch gables except for the "handles" or upturned ends.  I have a wok and can't see it in this type of roof. Unless it is upside down? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_gable#/media/File:Arras_GdPlace27_JPM.jpg

Comment: upturned ends along the Dutch gable shapes.

Comment: These look like what are called  a [gable end](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/gable%20end) in English.  They're a kind of wall at the end of a building.

Answer (score 2):

With the picture it makes some sense, but without it I would not have understood, because you have said nothing about the wall in question being the end wall of a house.
I imagined a free-standing wall, and it didn't make any sense. I would refer to that as a ["gable end"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gable_end) rather than a "wall", and then there would be more chance of it being understood. But I'm not sure how easily English speakers would understand it even then.